# python annotation return result

Tags: python, annotations

How can I return the result of the annotation and the result of the function being executed?
The code below only prints there result.
    import time

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        # print('%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
        #     (method.__name__, args, kw, te - ts))
        print(te - ts)
        return result

    return timed


@timeit
def f1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "abc"


result = f1()
print(type(result))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a tuple `(time_elapsed, function_result)`:

```
import time


def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        elapsed = te - ts
        return elapsed, result

    return timed


@timeit
def f1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "abc"


result = f1()
print(result)
> (1.003918170928955, 'abc')

elapsed, result = f1()
print(elapsed)
> 1.0018439292907715
print(result)
> abc
```